# matplotlib rotated text has an offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw some text within the boundaries of some lines. The lines can be rotated and therefore the text also needs to be rotated.

When I add the text without rotation, it seems to have the correct placement and size. After rotation though, it does not (best explained when you take a look at the picture).

Here is what I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.set_dpi( 100 )
fig.set_size_inches( 1, 1 )

# Plot diagonal line (45 degrees)
ax.plot((0, 0),(0, 10))
ax.plot((10, 10), (0, 10))
ax.plot((0, 10), (10, 10))
ax.plot((0, 10), (0, 0))
ax.plot((0,10),(1.3,1.3)) # font size 10 has 13 pixels, hence 1.3
ax.plot((3,10),(3,10))

# compute the offset of the line that is exactly 1.3 above the diagonal
d = np.array([-1,1])
d = d / np.sqrt(sum(d**2)) * 1.3
u = np.array([3,3]) + d
ax.plot( (u[0], 10+u[0]-u[1]), (u[1], 10 ))

# set limits so that it no longer looks on screen to be 45 degrees
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])

# Plot text
ax.text(0,0, 'In', fontsize=10 )
ax.text(4,0, 'Bbox', fontsize=10, bbox={"pad":0} )
ax.text(3,3, 'Out', fontsize=10, rotation=45, verticalalignment="bottom", \
    horizontalalignment="left", rotation_mode="anchor" )
ax.text(6,6, 'Bbox', fontsize=10, rotation=45, verticalalignment="bottom", \
    horizontalalignment="left", rotation_mode="anchor",bbox={"pad":0} )
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig( "test.pdf", bbox_inches="tight" )
```

This gives me the following output. Plot with rotated but offset text:

[image: Plot with rotated but offset text]

Note that the "Out" does not exactly fit within its two adjacent lines, as intended.
Anybody an idea on how to adjust/fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `"In"` text, you use `verticalalignment="baseline"` (implicitely, because it's the default). For the `"Out"` text you use `verticalalignment="bottom"` instead.

You may change this to `verticalalignment="baseline"` as well, or just leave it out completely.

```
ax.text(0,0, 'In', fontsize=10 )
ax.text(4,0, 'Bbox', fontsize=10, bbox={"pad":0} )
ax.text(3,3, 'Out', fontsize=10, rotation=45, 
        horizontalalignment="left", rotation_mode="anchor" )
ax.text(6,6, 'Bbox', fontsize=10, rotation=45, 
        horizontalalignment="left", rotation_mode="anchor",bbox={"pad":0} )
```

[image]

There is a nice example, [Demo text rotation mode](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_text_rotation_mode.html), on the matplotlib website, that explains this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously I overlooked the default parameter. Also thanks for the link to the demo. The matplotlib website is still a bit confusing to me...